# python list.append() - inconsistent output

Tags: python-2.7

I create 4 identical lists of lists L1, L2, L3, L4

```
>>> L0 = [[1]]
>>> L1 = [[1],[1]]
>>> L2 = [[1] for i in range(2)]
>>> L3 = L0 + L0
>>> L4 = [[1]] * 2

>>> L1
[[1], [1]]
>>> L2
[[1], [1]]
>>> L3
[[1], [1]]
>>> L4
[[1], [1]]

>>> L1 == L2 == L3 == L4
True
```

And apply list.append() to the first element in each

```
>>> L1[0].append(2) 
>>> L2[0].append(2)
>>> L3[0].append(2)
>>> L4[0].append(2)
```

with result

```
>>> L1
[[1, 2], [1]]
>>> L2
[[1, 2], [1]]
>>> L3
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
>>> L4
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Can somebody please explain the output for L3 and L4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all of these cases, the lists consist of *references* to other lists within them. In the case of `L3` and `L4` they are lists which consist of references to a single other list (`L0` for `L3` and for `L4` a single on-the-fly list `[1]`).

This is what the `[...]*2` syntax means -- make *two references* to the entry found inside the base list.

When you append, you modify the *referred-to list*, in all of its locations.

In other words, when you modify `L3[0]`, you are modifying a thing that `L3[1]` also refers to, so later when you query to see what `L3[1]` looks like, it reflects the now-modified version of what it has been referring to all along.

Equality between lists is defined in terms of equality of the ordered elements they contain. This applies recursively to lists of lists, and so on. So at base, your equality check is a question about the integers inside the lists, and *not* about the actual list object instances:

```
In [24]: x = [[1]]

In [25]: y = [[1]]

In [26]: x[0]
Out[26]: [1]

In [27]: y[0]
Out[27]: [1]

In [28]: x[0] == y[0]
Out[28]: True

In [29]: id(x[0])
Out[29]: 140728515456032

In [30]: id(y[0])
Out[30]: 140728514976728
```

Answer (score 1):

Because L3 and L4 are actually references so when you append to L3[0] and L4[0], you actually modify what they refer to.